# Setup data protection API depending on IConfiguration

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a .NET 6 web application that can run on the cloud (AWS Lambda) and on a physical server. I want to setup data protection differently depending on the current environment. My initial thought was to use the application configuration:

```cs
// Program.cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Setup builder.Configuration
// Setup builder.Services
ConfigureDpApi(builder);

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
// Setup app pipeline

app.Run();

static void ConfigureDpApi(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    AppConfiguration appConfig = builder.Configuration.Get<AppConfiguration>();
    if (appConfig.EnvironmentType == "AWS")
    {
        builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName(applicationName: "myapp")
            .PersistKeysToAWSSystemsManager(parameterNamePrefix: "/myapp/api/DataProtection");
    }
    else if (appConfig.EnvironmentType == "ON_PREMISE")
    {
        var directoryInfos = new DirectoryInfo(appConfig.KeysFolder);
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(appConfig.CertificatePath, appConfig.CertificatePassword);
        builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName(applicationName: "myapp")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(directoryInfos)
            .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(certificate);
    }
    else
    {
        // No DPAPI (local development, tests)
    }
}
```

My issue with this method is that it fails with the integration tests, because the test project overrides the configuration source *after* dependencies have been configured:

```cs
// Test API client initialization
var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
var apiClient = factory
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        // This line runs BEFORE Program.ConfigureDpApi()
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            // This line runs AFTER Program.ConfigureDpApi()
            config.Sources.Clear();
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.tests.json", optional: false);
        });
    })
    .CreateClient();
```

I'm stuck in this situation where I need my test configuration overrides to be available *before* DPAPI is setup (which happens during the `WebHostBuilder` configuration), which looks impossible to do (with reason).

Is there a way to configure DPAPI *after* my test project has overridden the configuration sources, meaning after `WebApplicationBuilder.Build()` has been called? Or should I give up on using `IConfiguration` altogether for this task and use a simpler method such as environment variables?

Comment: The version of .NET (Core) that you're using would be helpful, as well as the contents of `Program.cs`.